# Log Analytics workspace vs Storage Account

Tags: azure-storage-account, azure-log-analytics-workspace, azure-billing

I have just enabled monitoring for one of my Azure blob storage accounts and want to know if it is cheaper to send the logs to an log analytics workspace or another storage account?

Also, where can I find the current cost incurred for the data logged in log analytics workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I find the current cost incurred for the data logged in the log
> analytics workspace?

You can use the below query in your log analytics workspace to get the current cost incurred for the data logged in a Log Analytics workspace.

**Query:**

```
Usage 
| where TimeGenerated > startofday(ago(32d))
| where IsBillable == true
| summarize TotalvolumeGB = sum(Quantity) / 1024. by bin(TimeGenerated, 1d), Solution 
| render table
```

**Output:**
[image]

Alternatively, you can refer to this [**MS-Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/usage-estimated-costs#usage-and-estimated-costs) and see in the portal in the Azure log analytic workspace -> Usage and estimated costs.

> I have just enabled monitoring for one of my Azure blob storage accounts and want to know if sending the logs to a log analytics workspace or another storage account is cheaper.

You can use **`pricing calculator`** to compare the costs of sending logs to both [Azure log analytics workspace and storage account](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/).

**Reference:**
[Estimate costs with the Azure pricing calculator - Microsoft Cost Management | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/pricing-calculator)